# list the number of files changed in the last push /number of local commits went in one single push

Tags: git, continuous-integration

i need to get the number of local commits went in one push operations.
For each local commits in push operation there will be corresponding commits in remote.so one push will create many commits in remote.
I need to get the number of local commits for a single push. Otherwise i need to get the previous push id.so if my push has 3 local commits push operation will create 3 commits in remote . So my previous push ID will be HEAD^3.

But i need to  get this number .So how to know how many commits for a single push operation?is there any way to group based on push operation?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/58007917/1256452

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you have the following situation:

```
origin/branch    A---B
                      \
(local) branch         C---D
```

Then you `git push`:

```
origin/branch & (local) branch    A---B---C---D
```

After a `push`, the previous commit is `refs/remotes/origin/branch@{1}`. So, you could "undo" the push via:

```
git push -f origin refs/remotes/origin/branch@{1}:branch
```

Alternatively, if you want the number of commits actually changed:

```
git rev-list --count refs/remotes/origin/branch@{1}..refs/remotes/origin/branch
```

---

NOTES:

1. This works from the repository that made the `push`. I do not know if the command will work correctly from another repo - although I expect it would after the ref was updated with `git fetch`
2. I have no idea how this would handle a force push, or any other operation that forcible sets the ref to a specific commit id.

Comment: git rev-list --count refs/remotes/origin/branch@{1}..refs/remotes/origin/branch this is not giving the number of commits between two push .

Comment: git rev-parse 'origin/master@{1}'
12:42:36 fatal: Log for 'origin/master' only has 1 entries this is failing with this error.I got to know that git reflog should contain more than one entry-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23932860/get-list-of-files-to-recently-pushed-to-remote-git-branch.How to  make this work?

Comment: it works in local .is there anyway to do the same in a cloned repository

Comment: @ashal In a cloned repo this will be very inconsistent. I expect the same approach would work, but there's no way to tell if the change was due to a single push - IE if someone pushed twice, and then the clone updated references with `git fetch --all`, this approach would show the commits from BOTH pushes as a single update. The ONLY time this would work in a cloned repo is with this exact order of events: 1) Repo A and Repo B both update all refs 2) Repo A pushes some changes to `branch` 3) Repo B gets changes

Comment: @ashal Basically what you're looking for is very difficult/impossible to guarantee - because this isn't something that is (normally) considered important. It's available in some very specific situations, but I wouldn't recommend this as part of any regular process. Why are you looking for this information? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @ashal based on a second question I saw you wrote, I think you're really trying to ask "When my CI/CD server does a build, how do I determine the number of new commits being included?". If that is correct, you should ask that as a separate question - I think you'll get more helpful answers